# Is there a closed form for $\sum_p 1/2^p$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the sum $\sum_p {1 \over 2^p}$, where $p$ is the prime numbers. It obviously converges, because $\sum_{\Bbb N} {1 \over 2^n} = 1$, so that's an upperbound. And in fact this sum is approximately $0.414682509378 \dots$ but is there a closed form? Has this number been asked about previously?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeConstant.html

Comment: In other words, it has a name but nothing more.